# Running windows form using backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, system.reflection

I've an issue with runing windows forms under background worker.

```
private void workerDecrypter_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    route =(string) e.Argument;
    try
    {
        Application.Run(new Mono(route));
    }
    catch (Exception era) { }
}
```

`Mono` is windows form class, it creates new window in which I decrypt some text, when it finish process, it automatically close window. If there is not try catch, I get this exception

```
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `Application.Run` on the main thread, not in another thread. This will cause a TIA.

As a side note: if this is not the main form, there is no need to open that form in this way. You can easily do:

```
Mono m = new Mono(route);
m.Show();
```

If it is not a form, it should be an instance of `ApplicationContext`, which I don't think seeing your code.

Comment: It does this even in Main thread. It works like this, Main calls

    Application.Run(new Menu());

in Menu when button is clicked I do

    Mono m = new Mono(route);
    m.Show();
But still when Mono does it job it autocloses with system.reflection.targetinvocationexception

Comment: But that one runs in the main thread. Also, it creates the application context for you you don't need the second time.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your Help, I just found a bug in a code, where I used static variable to substring string and due to testing I was using shorter strings than this variable, so it failed at this point, when I checked InnerException line I found out on which line is the problem. Thank you for your help and time.